# MySQL - How To Make these two results in to a singe row

Tags: mysql, sql

Please refer to the image for a clear picture.
AQ, ICL rows created by me are for the same parent.

SQL:

```
SELECT  
CASE WHEN a.approval="Animal Quarntine Report Approval" AND a.approved = 1 THEN  "AQ-APPROVED" 
WHEN a.approval= "Animal Quarntine Report Approval" AND a.approved = 0 THEN "NOT APPROVED"
ELSE "" END AS AQ,
CASE 
WHEN a.approval = "ICL Approval" AND a.approved = 1 THEN  "ICL-APPROVED"
WHEN a.approval = "ICL Approval" AND a.approved = 0 THEN  "NOT APPROVED"
ELSE "" END AS ICL
FROM _39f2b669595dfe4d.`tabShipment Approvals` a
WHERE a.parent = "CLR/GFF/IMP/678/05/21";
```

I want to get a single row result, without creating another table.
Can someone please help me?
Thanks.

[Multiple rows into single row multi columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baQyP.png)

Thank you.

Eidt -

[The result I get with inner join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgDGM.png)

Comment: Hi, please prepare minimal reproducible example (see https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for such cases - it increases the chances that someone will help you.

Comment: In this case, you could do something like `select max(case when ... then ... end) as AQ, max(case when ... then ... end) as ICL from myTable`, optionally with some groupping, but it depends on your business needs.

Comment: Note that some spellings of quarantine have two 'a's

Answer (score -1):

You may need an ID or a field for a JOIN between the AQ and the ICL rows to make a JOIN, then you may use an autoreferenced join, something like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN a.approval="Animal Quarntine Report Approval" AND a.approved = 1 THEN "AQ-APPROVED" 
    WHEN a.approval= "Animal Quarntine Report Approval" AND a.approved = 0 THEN "NOT APPROVED" ELSE "" END AS AQ, 

CASE WHEN b.approval = "ICL Approval" AND b.approved = 1 THEN "ICL-APPROVED" 
    WHEN b.approval = "ICL Approval" AND b.approved = 0 THEN "NOT APPROVED" ELSE "" END AS ICL 
FROM _39f2b669595dfe4d.'tabShipment Approvals' a
INNER JOIN _39f2b669595dfe4d.'tabShipment Approvals' b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.parent = "CLR/GFF/IMP/678/05/21"
```

If you can show the other fields then the example can be more specific in the JOIN

Comment: Thank you very much joserobertog, I have tried your solution and has given me 4 rows, where the second row has what I wanted exactly! But to make that into a single row still a mystery. parent filed can be used as id. COuld you please help to clarify this?

I get something like this with the query,
AQ                                                 ICL
AQ - NOT APPROVED 
AQ - NOT APPROVED                   ICL -  APPROVED
(a blank row) 
                                                      ICL -  APPROVED

Comment: Thank you All!
With the help of joserobertog and suggestion by Adam Tokarski , I was able to achieve my target. Thanks all for spending your valuebale time. 
(In this case, you could do something like select max(case when ... then ... end) as AQ, max(case when ... then ... end) as ICL from myTable, optionally with some groupping, but it depends on your business needs. –)